# Mailchimp Template "Send to Mandrill option" is broken for actual email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, mandrill

I tried following this article: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-send-transactional-emails-from-rails-with-mandrill

I created a drag and drop template in Mailchimp and sent it to Mandrill.
The Mailchimp preview and test email is good. In Mandrill, the preview is good but the actual email is broken (e.g., there is no background color for the email body).

Creating a template from scratch is not an option because I need my client to be able to take advantage of the Mailchimp drag and drop to edit templates.

Comment: did you try sending email and color is still not showing. btw it's hard to help you without a code snippet of some sort.

Comment: Yes, I tried as mentioned on my post. The problem is the exported template  to Mandrill has internal css and not inlined.

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind without seeing the code is to manually edit the code block without background color. Try finding id="templateBody"  in a <tr> and setting its inline style.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your problem by making Mandrill automatically inline your Mailchimp's template CSS as explained [here](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/outbound-email/#inline-css) :

> To enable automatic inlining, select "Inline CSS Styles In HTML Emails" on the [Sending Defaults](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-options) page.